# Understanding WCAG resize text 1.4.4

Tags: accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

To meet WCAG AA, the resize text requirement (1.4.4) states that:

> 1.4.4 Resize text: Except for captions and images of text, text can be resized without assistive technology up to 200 percent without loss of content or functionality. (Level AA)

I have a web-app that I am trying to make pass AA but find this requirement un-clear. If in Chrome I zoom in at 200% on a monitor that is 2560x1440, the app looks perfect.  But if I use a 1024x800 monitor, the app does not look perfect.

What is the minimum resolution I need to support zooming at 200%, or am I missing the point?

Thanks.

Comment: "the app does not look perfect" is not  really a useful description of what isn't working as expected...

Comment: meaning content is hidden (other sections are overlapping it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the minimum resolution I need to support zooming at 200%, or am I missing the point?

You have to read [Understanding Success Criterion 1.4.10: Reflow](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/reflow.html)

> Success Criterion 1.4.10 Reflow (Level AA): Content can be presented without loss of information or functionality, and without requiring scrolling in two dimensions for:
>
> - Vertical scrolling content at a width equivalent to 320 CSS pixels;
> - Horizontal scrolling content at a height equivalent to 256 CSS pixels.

**This states that you should be able to zoom up to 400% on 1280 CSS pixels wide resolution**. There's also a paragraph which concerns *"The relation of Reflow to the Success Criterion 1.4.4 Resize Text"* and a note when *"text does not consistently increase its size as people zoom"* which refers to 1.4.4.

Comment: 1.4.4 and 1.4.10 are different requirements.  Yes, 1.4.10 talks about the monitor size and that scrolling in two directions should be avoided but 1.4.4 does not talk about size at all.  It's a tricky one to test for because as the OP said, it might look good with one browser size but look bad with a diff browser size.

Answer (score 0):

A typical situation where this should apply is, that text should wrap to the next line when the font-size gets too large to fit it into one line. So a one-line header's text will be wrapped, multi-line paragraphs and other elements will just wrap the text differently, so that all text remains visible on the screen.

Comment: I am not making simple headers/paragraphs, I'm making enterprise software with complex UIs. What it sounds like you are saying is that I need to handle ALL screen resolutions zoomed in at 200%.

Comment: yes. My example also applies to mobile phones, where visually handicapped persons should be able to read all text at double size without it overlapping or going out of its container or the screen.